# scala trouble with play framework JSON serialization from case class

Tags: scala, playframework

Play 2.2.1, scala 2.10

```
// PersonModel.scala
case class PersonModel(name: String, age: Long)

object PersonModel2 {    

  implicit object PersonModelFormat extends Format[PersonModel] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): PersonModel = PersonModel(
      (json \ "name").as[String],
      (json \ "age").as[Long])
    def writes(u: PersonModel): JsValue = JsObject(List(
      "name" -> JsString(u.name),
      "age" -> JsNumber(u.age)))
  }
```

sbt says

```
[error] PersonModel.scala:15: overriding method reads in trait Reads of type (json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.PersonModel];
[error]  method reads has incompatible type
[error]     def reads(json: JsValue): PersonModel = PersonModel(
[error]         ^
```

Comment: To explain why you get the error: the compiler is actually telling you that you are trying to override the method reads (defined in the Reads trait) returning a _different_ type than the one defined. You should return a JsResult[PersonModel]. Hence, you can just wrap your call to the PersonModel constructor with a JsSuccess(PersonModel(..., ...)) and change the return type of the method!

Answer (score 4):

In this case, since you're not doing fancy things with the output json (like changing the key names in the resulting json object), I'd go for:

```
case class PersonModel(name: String, age: Long)

import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val personModelFormat = Json.format[PersonModel]
```

This way, you can, for example

```
scala> val j = PersonModel("julien", 35)
j: PersonModel = PersonModel(julien,35)
scala> println(Json.toJson(j))
{"name":"julien","age":35}
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception)

HTH,

Julien

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed in recent versions, I'd say for the better.  In `2.2.x`, you'd do it this way, using the new *functional syntax* and combinators:

```
 import play.api.libs.json._
 import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._


 implicit val PersonModelFormat: Format[PersonModel] = (
     (__ \ "name").format[String] and
     (__ \ "age").format[Long]
 )(PersonModel.apply, unlift(PersonModel.unapply))
```

Much shorter!

The documentation for `2.2.x` http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaJsonCombinators provides a good explanation for the rationale for the change.

Answer (score 0):

For single usage there is an inline solution:

```
Json.writes[PersonModel].writes(personModelInstance)  // returns JsObject
```

From documentation:
*macro-compiler replaces Json.writes[User] by injecting into compile chain the exact code you would write yourself*